# How can I set my y axis for a bar + point plot to range between 2 non-zero negative numbers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to get my y axis for my bar plot to go from -50 (at the bottom) to -25 (at the top). Essentially do `coord_cartesian()` and then scale_y_reverse(), but that doesn't work. It'll only give it to me from -25 at the bottom to -50 at the top.

If I do `scale_y_reverse(limits = c(-50, -25))` I get this:

> ```
> Warning messages: 
>   1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
>   2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_errorbar). 
>   3: Removed 16 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
> ```

I've also tried using `ylim`, but it makes the plot with no bar.

```r
ggplot(avg_AP_threshold, aes(name, average)) +
    geom_col(width = 0.3, fill = "grey60", color = "black") +
    geom_point(data = AP_threshold, position = position_nudge(x = -0.1)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-50, -25))

 ggplot(avg_AP_threshold, aes(name, average)) +
    geom_col(width = 0.3, fill = "grey60", color = "black") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = average - sd, ymax = average + sd, width = 0.1)) +
    geom_point(data = AP_threshold, position = position_nudge(x = -0.1)) +
    ylim(-50, -25)
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: img1]

This is what my code does.

[image: img2]

Comment: Are you saying you want your bars to have a baseline of -50 and to go up to -25? There are some solutions to that in prior questions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298209/ggplot2-shift-the-baseline-of-barplot-geom-bar-to-the-minimum-data-value/40298742#40298742   If your question is different, please draw a picture or add some clarification to the body of your question.

Comment: I added an image to my post (in a link). Honestly I'm pretty new to R so my code is definitely inefficient. It could be an issue with the way I've loaded the data in - the solutions in the link you provided aren't working right.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't understand how your code's result is different from what you want.

Comment: Added another image using this bit of code: 
scale_y_reverse() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-50, -25))
The y axis goes from -25 to -50 instead of -50 to -25

Answer (score 0):

Fake data:

```
AP_threshold <- data.frame(
  name = LETTERS[1:2],
  value = rnorm(10, mean = -30, sd = 10)
)
```

Avg data:

```
library(dplyr)
avg_AP_threshold <- AP_threshold %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(average = mean(value),
            sd = sd(value))
```

`geom_col` has a baseline of zero. If you want a negative baseline, one option is to shift your data and then shift your labels the opposite way:

```
negative_shift = 50
ggplot(avg_AP_threshold, aes(name, average + negative_shift)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.3, fill = "grey60", color = "black") +
  geom_point(data = AP_threshold, 
             aes(y = value + negative_shift),
             position = position_nudge(x = -0.1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = average - sd + negative_shift, 
                    ymax = average + sd + negative_shift), width = 0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(y) y - negative_shift)
```

[image]

Comment: I have a set of data that should make up 1 bar. ie data from a bunch of samples, where the geom_bar is the average of the points and geom_point is the raw data for each sample. The final output should be 1 bar with a bunch of points over it.

Comment: Updated to extend to apply the same logic to each layer.